# WordPress, отправка письма с вложениями

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, вёрстка, веб-сервер, wordpress-плагины

У меня есть обработчик формы `success.php`, который находится в корне установки WordPress. В письме, кроме текста, должны во вложении отправляться PDF файлы.

Клиент через админку должен иметь возможность управлять этими файлами, которые отправляются (изменять, добавлять и т.д).

Я правильно понимаю, что для этого мне нужно в `$_POST` передавать полный путь к файлам, а потом уже использовать их в обработчике?

В форме пробовал сделать скрытый input, а в value вывести путь к файлу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для произвольных полей использовал плагин ACF, поле с типом "Файл", которое возвращет ссылку на файл.

Затем в обработчике этот путь пытался присвоить переменной `$attachments`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в письме файл почему-то не приходит во вложении, только текстовая информация. Хоть сам путь к файлу: `$file = htmlspecialchars($_POST["file"]);` успешно приходит в обработчик.

А если вот так написать, то файл успешно приходит во вложении на почту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как мне отправить файлы почтой и чтобы клиент мог управлять этими файлами через админку?

Comment: Что у вас выдает var_dump( $_POST['file'] )?

Comment: Спасибо, благодаря вам я понял в чем причина, var_dump( $_POST['file'] ) выдает строку с абсолютной ссылкой на файл и начинается с http: //site-name.com... А на самом деле нужно чтобы путь начинался с /home/ursgrfs/site-name.com... Как мне теперь переделать, чтобы путь к файлу был в таком формате?

Comment: В ссылке ursgrfs - это мое имя пользователя на хостинге

Comment: Нашел решение, нужно передавать ID вложения и использовать функцию get_attached_file(), которая получает абсолютный (серверный) путь вложения (прикрепленного файла) по переданному ID вложения

Answer (score 0):

нужно передавать ID вложения и использовать функцию get_attached_file(), которая получает абсолютный (серверный) путь вложения (прикрепленного файла) по переданному ID вложения